# Why does this while loop cause an infinite loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, logic, infinite-loop

```
public void calculate(int input) {

inputField.setText("" + input);

while (input >= 1) {

    if (input % 2 == 0) {
        input = input / 2;
    } else {
        input = (input * 3) + 1;
    }
    output.append("" + input);
    }

}
```

The output variable is a JTextArea and inputField is a JTextField where the user enters an integer.

I call the method and initialize the input variable here:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    input = Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText());
    calculate(input);

    }

}
```

Every time the value of input is even, it is divided by 2 so it should eventually reach 1, correct? Then why does this while loop cause an infinite loop?

Comment: hint : what happens when `input == 1`?

Comment: 1 4 2 1 4 2 1 4 2 1 4 2 1 4 2 1 4 2

Comment: "Every time the value of input is even, it is divided by 2 so it should eventually reach 1, correct? Then why does this while loop cause an infinite loop?" - perhaps you could ask yourself, where the difference between your program and your assumption lies that the program should exit when reaching "1".

Comment: Thanks everyone. The biggest mistake I made here was indeed thinking the loop would stop executing when input reached 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your condition - because even if you reach 1, the loop will continue. 
Replace `while (input >= 1)` with `while (input > 1)`

Answer (score 0):

This gives an infinite loop because `input` can never get to zero or below.  There is no even number `>=1` which when halved gives zero, and no odd number `>=1` which when tripled gives `-1`.  So `input` will always be `>=1` and you have an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

If [the Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) is true that loop will always reach 1 -- the problem is that you don't stop looping at 1 :)

Change `while (input >= 1)` to `while (input > 1)`.

Comment: Ok, that was poorly phrased.